# PostGIS Query: All rows within 1 hour of each other which intersect

Tags: postgis, sql

I'm using postgres (postgis) and i want to perform a query that returns all rows which geometries intersect and have a timestamp within 1 hour from each other.

**What would the SQL statement look like?**

table looks like this:

```
id   { integer }    
name { character varying }
bounds { geometry }  
timestamp { timestamp with time zone }

// purposely left out bounds in the table example below (not necessary)

id   name       timestamp
---+----------+--------------------------------
1    one        "2010-09-24 21:10:39.515+00"
2    two        "2010-09-16 09:21:09.362+00"
3    three      "2010-07-08 00:00:46.549+00"
...
```

**EDIT #1**

Not including the intersect matching here is an example: for every row give me any other rows that are within 1 hour:

```
select * from myTable order by t

 id |               t               
----+-------------------------------
  9 | 2011-07-15 18:20:20.05+02
 10 | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02
 11 | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02
 13 | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02
 14 | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02
(5 rows)

result of needed query:

 id |  matchid |  origTime                  | matchTime
----+----------+----------------------------+------------------------------
  9 |   10     | 2011-07-15 18:20:20.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02
 10 |    9     | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02  | 2011-07-15 18:20:20.05+02
 10 |   11     | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02
 11 |   10     | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:05:00.05+02
 11 |   13     | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02  | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02
 11 |   14     | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02  | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02
 13 |   11     | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02
 13 |   14     | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02  | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02
 14 |   11     | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02  | 2011-07-15 19:40:20.05+02
 14 |   13     | 2011-07-15 20:35:11.05+02  | 2011-07-15 20:31:01.05+02
(10 rows)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
select
  m1.id as id,
  m2.id as match_id,
  m1.startDate as origTime,
  m2.startDate as matchTime
from
  myTable m1 inner join
  myTable m2 on st_intersects(m1.geom, m2.geom)
  and (m1.startDate - m2.startDate <= interval '1 hour'
       or -(m1.startDate - m2.startDate) <= interval '1 hour')
  and m1.id != m2.id
```